# Looping through Json Arrays from API

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I am currently trying to loop and add each element of the quantity of each bid and ask which appears as bids[0][1], bids[1][1], bids[1][2] and add each element in the Array sequence. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

I tried adding the array but I am unable to turn the Json data to code here. Below is the API reference

I tried the code:

```
const binanceTrade = JSON.parse(data)

const bidsQuantity = binanceTrade.bids[0][1]

const askQuantity = binanceTrade.asks[0][1]


for(var i = 0; i<bidsQuantity.length; i++){

  var j = 1;

  bidsQuantity = bidsQuantity.push(binanceTrade.bids[j][1])
  console.log(bidsQuantity)

  j++
  //bids[0][1] + bids[1][2]
}
```

And the public Binance API route for reference: https://api.binance.com/api/v3/depth?symbol=BTCUSDT&limit=5

Comment: ` bidsQuantity` isn't an array. So there's no `bidsQuantity.length` or `bidsQuantity.push()`.

Comment: You're resetting `j=1` each time through the loop, so `j++` has no effect.

Comment: `bidsQuantity = bidsQuantity.push(...)` is a bad idea (once it is an array).  Instead just do `bidsQuantity.push(...)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reduce()` to loop over the `bids` and `asks` arrays, totaling the second element of each item.

```
const binanceTrade = JSON.parse(data);
const bidsQuantity = binanceTrade.bids.reduce((acc, [_, quantity]) => acc + quantity, 0);
const asksQuantity = binanceTrade.asks.reduce((acc, [_, quantity]) => acc + quantity, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to use `map`

```
const bidsQuantity = binanceTrade.bids.map((bids) => {
    return bids[1];
});
```

You can do this again in a similar way for the asks

Answer (score 0):

You Can try this :

```
let bids_count = 0
for (var i=0 ;i < data.bids.length;i++) {
bids_count += bids_count + Number(data.bids[i][1])
}
```

similarly for data.asks

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).